# How to create key value pair from an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, dictionary

I have an array object with following data:

```
const arr = [
{
  key: 'mykey1597855209',
  integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='
},
{
  key: 'mykey159785520915978552101597855212',
  integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='
},
{
  key: 'mykey15978552091597855210',
  integrity: 'sha512-lcddfd=='
},
{
  key: 'otherkey15978552091597855210',
  integrity: 'sha512-abcdfd=='
}];
```

I want to create `key` `value` pair from the the `arr[]` object such that `integrity` becomes key and the `key` becomes value

> Desired Output is something like below:

```
{
  "sha512-T9JWj==": [
    "mykey1597855209",
    "mykey159785520915978552101597855212"
  ],
  "sha512-lcddfd==": [
    "mykey15978552091597855210"
  ],
  "sha512-abcdfd==": [
    "otherkey15978552091597855210"
  ]
}
```

I have written following code:

```js
const arr = [{
    key: 'mykey1597855209',
    integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='
  },
  {
    key: 'mykey159785520915978552101597855212',
    integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='
  },
  {
    key: 'mykey15978552091597855210',
    integrity: 'sha512-lcddfd=='
  },
  {
    key: 'otherkey15978552091597855210',
    integrity: 'sha512-abcdfd=='
  }
];
const result = Object.assign(...arr.map(a => ({
  [a.integrity]: a.key
})));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Use a reduce and push to an array - this is not valid `{
   'mykey1597855209',
   'mykey159785520915978552101597855212'
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arr = [{key: 'mykey1597855209',integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='},{key: 'mykey159785520915978552101597855212',integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='},{key: 'mykey15978552091597855210',integrity: 'sha512-lcddfd=='},{key: 'otherkey15978552091597855210',integrity: 'sha512-abcdfd=='}];

let map = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({_, integrity }) => [integrity, []]));
arr.forEach(({key, integrity}) => map[integrity].push(key));

console.log(map);
```

Or `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{key: 'mykey1597855209',integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='},{key: 'mykey159785520915978552101597855212',integrity: 'sha512-T9JWj=='},{key: 'mykey15978552091597855210',integrity: 'sha512-lcddfd=='},{key: 'otherkey15978552091597855210',integrity: 'sha512-abcdfd=='}];

let map = arr.reduce((acc, { key, integrity }) => {
  acc[integrity] = acc[integrity] || [];
  acc[integrity].push(key);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(map);
```

Comment: `'sha512-T9JWj=='` has two key values `'mykey1597855209','mykey159785520915978552101597855212'` but is showing only one in the output

Comment: Well, you cannot duplicate the same integrity value, since it is a key of the final object. How did you imagine the output then? Note that the desired output you listed in your question is invalid.

Comment: Anyway, you can use sub arrays. See update of my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have also updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it like this:

```
let map = {};

arr.forEach({ key, integrity } => map[integrity] = key);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {    
    acc[curr.integrity] = (acc[curr.integrity]) ? 
                          [ ...acc[curr.integrity], curr.key ] : 
                          [ curr.key ]    
    return acc;
}, {})
```